# Unable to insert keyframes with color ramp

Tags: animation

When I try to insert keyframes on the color ramp in the shading tabenter image description here (hovering over the position and pressing I, and right clicking it and pressing insert keyframe) no keyframes are created. when i try to do it again it gives me the option to delete keyframes but they were not there in the first place, its like a sort of "ghost keyframe" that blender think exists but it doesnt. I've tried playing the animation but it does not play.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the object that has the material is selected (or disable the *Only Show Selected* option in the *Dope Sheet* if it is activated), and also that the *ColorRamp* node is selected.